# how to enable Apache Arrow in Pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, pyarrow

I am trying to enable Apache Arrow for conversion to Pandas. I am using:

pyspark 2.4.4
pyarrow 0.15.0
pandas 0.25.1
numpy 1.17.2

This is the example code

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["x"]))
```

I got this warning message

```py
c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:714: UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.api.python.PythonSQLUtils.readArrowStreamFromFile.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessage(MessageSerializer.java:543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$3.readNextBatch(ArrowConverters.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$3.<init>(ArrowConverters.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.getBatchesFromStream(ArrowConverters.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$readArrowStreamFromFile$2.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$readArrowStreamFromFile$2.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.readArrowStreamFromFile(ArrowConverters.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.python.PythonSQLUtils$.readArrowStreamFromFile(PythonSQLUtils.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.python.PythonSQLUtils.readArrowStreamFromFile(PythonSQLUtils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandasUDF and pyarrow 0.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273063/pandasudf-and-pyarrow-0-15-0)

Answer (score 52):

We made a change in 0.15.0 that makes the default behavior of pyarrow incompatible with older versions of Arrow in Java -- your Spark environment seems to be using an older version.

Your options are

- Set the environment variable `ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1` from where you are using Python
- Downgrade to pyarrow < 0.15.0 for now.

Comment: Wow, this has been bugging me for days! I had a very simple groupBy.apply statement with a PandasUDF method and it was constantly failing where it didn't before. Turns out that the build environment had started using 0.15 ><.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER. Please put the checkmark underneath it :)  thank you @Wes McKinney

Comment: is this answer still current?

Answer (score 13):

For calling my pandas UDF in my Spark 2.4.4 cluster with `pyarrow==0.15`. I struggled with setting the `ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1` flag as mentioned above successfully.

I set the flag in (1) the command line via `export` on the head node, (2) via  `spark-env.sh` and `yarn-env.sh` on all nodes in the cluster, and (3) in the pyspark code itself from my script on the head node.  None of these worked to actually set this flag inside of the udf, for unknown reasons.

The simplest solution I found was to call this **inside** the udf:

```
    @pandas_udf("integer", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    def foo(*args):
        import os
        os.environ["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "1"
        #...
```

Hopefully this saves someone else several hours.

Comment: Thank you! The other solutions did not work for us, but this did. AWS EMR 2.4.x, so perhaps the config setting is not so easy on EMR as it is on other spark solutions.

Comment: This saved me several hours. For some reason my dev endpoint has pyarrow 0.13.0 which works fine and the AWS Glue cluster has 0.16.0 which fails. This solution is a good workaround until we fix it properly.

Comment: Use `--conf spark.executorEnv.ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1` when launching your job. If you are using AWS Glue, pass it using the section "Job parameters" (a key/value properties). The key is `--conf` and the value is `spark.executorEnv.ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1`