# PySpark 2.4.4 toPandas fail with ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, pyarrow

On spark dataframe when I do a 'toPandas' i end up with this error:

> pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
>
> File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.4.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2122, in toPandas
>
> File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.4.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2180, in _collectAsArrow
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Spark version - 2.4.4
Pyarrow version - 0.14.1

The same works with Spark 2.3.1 and pyarrow 0.9.0.

Any help with solving this with spark 2.4.4?

Comment: also experiencing this issue. Hopefully someone will weigh in at some point

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269115/how-to-enable-apache-arrow-in-pyspark/58273294#58273294